# System goes unresponsive for minutes, I suspect journalctl

Tags: server, 22.04, systemd, systemd-journald

We have an server application running on Ubuntu 22.04. The application logs are pretty spammy.

```bash
journalctl -S -1hour | wc --lines
121349
journalctl -S -1hour | wc --bytes
32382836
```

Once in a while a server will become completely unresponsive for several minutes. The CPU will go to 100% and our applications are so unresponsive that other agents stop reporting any metrics.

When the incident is over we notice that our application didn't crash does log a bunch of timeout errors because it wasn't able to do anything for the last few minutes. However, it does just continue working after that.

I found this in `/var/log/syslog`

```
Feb 28 17:44:29 ip-10-11-0-205 kernel: [81118.252411] systemd[1]: Started ntp-systemd-netif.service.
Feb 28 17:44:53 ip-10-11-0-205 kernel: [81142.367869] systemd[1]: ntp-systemd-netif.service: Deactivated successfully.
Feb 28 17:45:13 ip-10-11-0-205 kernel: [81162.387816] systemd[1]: systemd-journald.service: State 'stop-watchdog' timed out. Killing.
Feb 28 17:45:14 ip-10-11-0-205 kernel: [81162.731840] systemd[1]: systemd-journald.service: Killing process 117 (systemd-journal) with signal SIGKILL.
Feb 28 17:45:17 ip-10-11-0-205 kernel: [81165.657264] systemd[1]: systemd-journald.service: Main process exited, code=killed, status=9/KILL
Feb 28 17:45:17 ip-10-11-0-205 kernel: [81165.696972] systemd[1]: systemd-journald.service: Failed with result 'watchdog'.
Feb 28 17:45:18 ip-10-11-0-205 kernel: [81166.651435] systemd[1]: systemd-journald.service: Consumed 2min 5.531s CPU time.
Feb 28 17:45:25 ip-10-11-0-205 kernel: [81174.079307] systemd[1]: systemd-journald.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 1.
Feb 28 17:45:25 ip-10-11-0-205 kernel: [81174.085466] systemd[1]: Stopped Journal Service.
Feb 28 17:45:25 ip-10-11-0-205 kernel: [81174.200482] systemd[1]: systemd-journald.service: Consumed 2min 5.531s CPU time.
Feb 28 17:45:29 ip-10-11-0-205 kernel: [81177.822409] systemd[1]: Starting Journal Service...
Feb 28 17:45:35 ip-10-11-0-205 kernel: [81183.821550] systemd-journald[240259]: File /var/log/journal/ec212477ed3f3049adade2e820950984/system.journal corrupted or uncleanly shut down, renaming and replacing.
Feb 28 17:45:38 ip-10-11-0-205 kernel: [81187.226010] systemd[1]: Started Journal Service.
```

So it sounds like `systemd-journal` is causing the issue.

Questions:

1. Is this just taking a long time to process my logs?
2. Why does it need to hog the whole host?
3. If yes, are there some settings I can change so this doesn't go crazy? (e.g. trim logs more frequently, etc)

Comment: If you open `htop`, what has the most "TIME+"?

Comment: The host this happened on is lost so I don't have that information but on another host that hasn't had this issue yet it's mostly the primary application that serves web traffic. The secondary stuff is a few monitoring agents and further down the list is /lib/systemd/systemd-journald

Comment: Are you sure it's CPU not disk that goes to 100% with `State 'stop-watchdog' timed out. Killing.`? I would consider disabling swap if that happens

Comment: I think you might be right. I checked some other metrics and 1 of 4 cpu cores was pegged so CPU was 27% or something.

Also, there was a ton of disk read activity during the incident too.

Are you thinking that it used too much memory and it spilled over into swap?

If that's true then it explains why other applications were affected because they would have had their memory pages swapped to disk and had to read them again.

I could disable swap but then that would probably mean if this happens my app would crash instead of slow down. Would putting memory limits on journald work?

Comment: I don't think journald would overuse memory, so limits shouldn't work. The memory limits should be placed on your app so that it fails fast instead of causing a cascading failure of thrashing

Comment: Ok, i'll try putting a memory limit on the application. thanks!